# How to extract specific part of a file delimited by multiple lines of asterisks?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I am trying to extract different parts of text from a file separated by multiple lines of * characters. The content of the file looks like this:

```
**************************
**************************
abc123
abc1234
**************************
**************************
123abc
**************************
12ab34
**************************
**************************
12345
**************************
**************************
6789
abcd
1234
**************************
**************************
```

What would be the way to extract for example the fifth part of the file? 
The fifth part contains the following rows:

```
6789
abcd
1234
```

I tried using `grep` :

```
grep -E -v '([^\*]*\*)' filename
```

The output of the command is:

```
abc123
abc1234
123abc
12ab34
12345
6789
abcd
1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding one more generic solution here.

```
awk '/^\*+/{if(prev!~/^\*/){count++}} count==5 && !/^\*/;{prev=$0}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk` and shown samples only.

```
awk -v FS="*+" -v RS="^$" '{gsub(/^\n+|\n+$/,"",$10);print $10}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** More generic solution.

```
awk '/^\*/{count++} count==9 && $0!~/^\*/' Input_file
```